# Warnings after changing Sudden Motion Sensor with pmset

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, audio, battery, sleep-wake

I'm following the [Optimisation Guide from Avid](http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/troubleshooting/Optimize-10-11) for my Pro Tools software.

On the **Disable Sudden Motion Sensor** section, I get these errors after entering `sudo pmset -a sms 0` in Terminal for turning the Sudden Motion Sensor off:

1. `Warning: Idle sleep timings for "Battery Power: may not behave as expected. - Disk sleep should be non-zero whenever system sleep is non-zero.`
2. `Warning: Idle sleep timings for "AC Power" may not behave as expected. Disk sleep should be non-zero whenever system sleep is non-zero.`

I then typed: `sudo pmset -g` to verify it it had worked (as per the guide's instruction) and got this:

```
Battery Power       -1*
AC Power        -1
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         10800
 standby              1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             0
 gpuswitch            2
 disksleep            0
 sleep                2 (sleep prevented by coreaudiod, com.apple.WebKit.WebContent)
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         2
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

I have no idea what any of  this means (the errors or the table).

Being worried, I then re-enabled the Sudden Motion Sensor using: `sudo pmset -a sms 1`, however, I was met with the same two errors messages that I posted above when turning it off.

I'm a bit worried, have I messed something up and how do I correct these errors?

### Note

The message `sleep prevented by coreaudiod, com.apple.WebKit.WebContent`, did not appear a 2nd time when repeating. No idea what this is either.

System: Macbook Early 2015 13" Retina OS X El Capitan 11.6

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out, it was due to **Turn display off after x** settings. Setting it to **Never** fixed this.

I'm the creator of this post. I'd close the thread but it won't let me log back into the account. Feel free to delete it.

Comment: This is a valid answer and should be marked as such.  Try getting in touch with the moderators of this site to merge your accounts